# Google Kubernetes Engine - NEG unhealthy after upgrade to 1.25

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I just upgraded GKE to 1.25 from 1.24 and NEG Health Checks started to be RED - unhealthy.

I'm using NEG ie. for Ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-neg
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"80":{}}}'
spec: # Service's specification
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
```

The Health Check is very basic TCP health check on port 80:

```
{
  "checkIntervalSec": 1,
  "description": "",
  "healthyThreshold": 2,
  "kind": "compute#healthCheck",
  "logConfig": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "name": "neg-tcp-health-check",
  "tcpHealthCheck": {
    "portSpecification": "USE_SERVING_PORT",
    "proxyHeader": "NONE"
  },
  "timeoutSec": 1,
  "type": "TCP",
  "unhealthyThreshold": 2
}
```

To replicate you can use Nginx Ingress
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.5.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

I'm somewhere missing some deprecation or change in APIs can someone point me to right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With upgrade some network tags were changed and I did missed that, always check your firewall rules for NEG!

Gcloud command example:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create fw-allow-health-check-and-proxy \
   --network=default \
   --action=allow \
   --direction=ingress \
   --target-tags={NEWTWORK_TAG} \
   --source-ranges=130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16 \
   --rules=tcp:{ALLOW_PORT}
```